# How can I add Id as Integer in Firebase Database In android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want an Id to be integer and  do not want to  used Push.For 
example:

```
{
   "chats": {
    "1": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "messages": {
        "1": { "sender": "ghopper", "message": "Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth." },
        "2": { ... },
     }
    },
    "2": { ... }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
define globe  int i=1;
++i;
databaseReference.child("chats").child(i).setValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

the `push()` method generate the random key so try this

```
mRef.child("chats").child(your_id).setValue();
```